# MATLAB .....Get audio data from recordObj while recording function is in progress

Tags: matlab

The matlab recording function"record ( recordObj, samplingTime )" needs 0.8 second plus the sampling time to be executed.
this means that if i want to record for only 0.2 second the execution time of this function will be 1 second. 
I am working on a real time processing project in which I need to record 0.2 second files with high frequency and make real time processing on each file. 
So i tried to record a long record and access it every 0.2 second.
So I wonder if i can access recordObj while the recording function is in progress .
I tried this code but i got error as the matlab couldn't access "myvoise" while recording is in progress. thanks in advance

```
clc
% clear all
% myVoice = audiorecorder;
% % Define callbacks to show when
% % recording starts and completes.
% myVoice.StartFcn = 'disp(''Start speaking.'')';
% myVoice.StopFcn = 'disp(''End of recording.'')';
% record(myVoice,20);
% y=getaudiodata(myVoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Matlab is not really designed for real time processing. But if you really need it, look into the DSP Systems Toolbox, which provide this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't access myVoice because record is a not blocking function, this means that after execution of `record(myVoice,20)` immediately `getaudiodata` is executed but myVoice has not yet captured any data. If instead you use `recordblocking(myVoice,20)` then this will block flow of your code for 20 seconds. So myVoice now will contain data for 20 seconds and `getaudiodata` will be successfully executed.

Because you want real time operation I suggest set `myVoice.TimerFcn = 'callbackfcn(myVoice)'` and also set `myVoice.TimerPeriod=period`. Where callback fcn will be  a user specified function in which you call `data = getaudiodata(myVoice)`. This function will be called every period seconds during execution. So in this way you can call `record(myVoice,20)` and after period(s) getaudiodata will be successfully executed because myVoice already has period(in s) of audio data.

Be aware of that every time `getaudiodata` is executed will acquire all data of my voice from the beggining of recording, so you can skip every period the previous acquired data (i*period/Fs) where i is the time the callback function is executed(beginning from zero). Be also awhere of that myVoice will be buffered in memory, so if you record for a long period of time at high sampling frequency matlab performance will deteriorate

Comment: Your answer is unreadable!
Improve formatting and insert spaces in between to improve readability.